# How to run php function onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onclick

i have created my wordpress plugin and now i want to run its shortcode function onclick in new window. I don't know it is possible or not but i am trying to achieve this with `window.open`. Any help is highly appreciated. here is my code:

```
<a onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">
  Click Me
</a>
```

My shortcode looks like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_gallery product_id=“0”]');?>
```

Comment: In a new window of the same page or some other page? Is it a wordpress template?
Do you pass any parameters or not?

Comment: it is not a wordpress template. i am working on page with above values. plugin is working fine with shortcode but what i want is to run my plugin output in new window.

Comment: `what i want is to run my plugin output in new window` - please consider changing the title of your post, maybe something like `Wordpress: How to direct plugin output to new window`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side lanuage, while JS is not. So if you want to run PHP code you need to send commands to the server. The easiest way to do so is just opening your .php server page that will process your request and will send back to your original page.

For your user it will look like a refresh.

I would recommend you using jquery do something like this, at the bottom of your page in

```
<script>
$("#yourlink").click(function(){
window.location.href = "http://yourpage.com?someparameters";

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow detect that you're now running your page in the new window. You can pass in a query param like so:

```
<script>
function openPopup() {
  const url = new URL(document.URL);
  url.searchParams.append('popup', true);
  return window.open(
    url.toString(), '_blank', 
    'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes'
  );
}
</script>
<a onclick="openPopup" ...
```

Then in PHP:

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_GET['popup'])) {
    echo do_shortcode('[my_gallery product_id=“0”]');
  } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. it looks good but after putting this, Click Me do nothing. i used `<a onclick="openPopup">
  Click Me
</a>` in this way: